# Jquery speed, using .html(string) is really really slow, how can I speed this up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I've got a function that is taking on average 250ms to complete. I would like to do this in much less time, <20ms if I can <10ms would be best.

```
function updateDisplay() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data('ansi');
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.screen.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.screen[i].length; j++) {
            html += data.screen[i][j];
        }
        html += '<br />';
    }
    var create = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('Build html: ' + (create-start));
    $this.html(html);
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('Update html: ' +(end-create));
}
```

I'm calling this function in side a `setInterval` to update my display, building the html string is 0ms to 1ms each frame, but the update html is anywhere from 100ms to 300ms. Is there anyway to get this to be faster?

**Bah, having chrome inspector open to watch the console was adding a huge delay**
This is my current function (Basically a drop if from CD Sanchez). Without the inspector open It's running at about 50ms for the update html. This is much better, but would like to get it to <20ms if I can.

```
function updateDisplay() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data('ansi');
    var html = Array();
    for (var i = 0, length1 = data.screen.length; i < length1; ++i) {
        var a = data.screen[i]; // cache object
        for (var j = 0, length2 = a.length; j < length2; ++j) {
            html.push(a[j]); // push to array
        }
        html.push('<br />');
    }
    var create = new Date().getTime();
    this.innerHTML = html.join(''); // use innerHTML
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    $('#debug').html('Build html: ' + (create-start) + '<br/>Update html: ' + (end-create));
}
```

**Sample value of html** - 1st row, up to the `<br>`

```
<span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">┌</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">─</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">┐</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;">&nbsp;</span><br>
```

**Example** - [here](http://justinzaun.com/ansi/), only tested in chrome so far. Known knot to work in IE yet...

**Update**
I've converted my code to use a canvas and draw directly to that. I'm not sure if I'm doing it the best way or not as its my first time using the canvas. As it stands now I'm at around 20ms. Thats the upper end of where I'm happy, 10ms would be much better though.

I'm not sure if I can define a foreground and background color in the style and remove the `fillRect` call or not, that would speed things up a lot if I could. The other issue is the font doesn't look as crisp as it did as pure html, not sure if I can fix that or not. The example linked above has been updated.

```
function updateDisplay() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data('ansi');
    for (var i = 0, length1 = data.screen.length; i < length1; ++i) {
        var a = data.screen[i]; // cache object
        for (var j = 0, length2 = a.length; j < length2; ++j) {
            data.ctx.fillStyle = a[j][0];
            data.ctx.fillRect (8*j, 14 * i, 8, 14);
            data.ctx.fillStyle = a[j][1];
            data.ctx.fillText(a[j][2], 8*j, 14 * i);
        }
    }
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    $('#debug').html('Frame Time: ' + (end-start));
}
```

**Last Update**
`ctx.fillText` is quite slow and not accurate enough for my purposes. I've defined my own font as a 8x16 array and draw each pixel with a `ctx.fillRect`. This is much much faster and dealing with the font subsystem it seams.

Comment: Have you tried `this.innerHTML = html` -- it might be a bit faster.

Comment: @CD Sanchez - not a large increase, 100-250ms is what I see now. If it makes a difference the html is a bunch of `span`s with a single character in each.

Comment: Have you tried using the Firebug profiler? It may point out some areas that are taking a long time to execute.

Comment: @Justin808: Well, I think most of the time you're measuring is spent by the HTML engine rending the markup (which might be pretty complex depending on how big your data set is). I can't really think of anything you can do with JavaScript that will improve that time substantially.

Comment: It's hard to say anything useful here without seeing the actual string passed to `html()`.  Given a testcase, it shouldn't be hard to see where time is spent, though.... at least on some browsers.

Comment: @CD Sanchez - the size is 80x24, @Boris Zbarsky I'll update with a sample.

Comment: If it's 80x24, then that's 1920 different spans + other misc elements. Definitely the bottleneck.

Comment: RE: Your last update: Do they all have `background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;` as the style or will it occasionally differ? Have you considered a common CSS class for these spans? Or you can also wrap it with a `div` and set the properties on the parent container. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @CD Sanchez - they are currently all the same, but in the future they will change. Think of this as a old dos screen, 80x24 characters wide. I'll see if I can upload what I got someplace so you can see the whole bit of code and effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some very small optimizations that I doubt will help much, but here you go anyways:

```
function updateDisplay() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data('ansi');
    var html = [];
    for (var i = 0, length1 = data.screen.length; i < length; ++i) {
        var a = data.screen[i]; // cache object
        for (var j = 0, length2 = a.length; j < length2; ++j) {
            html.push(a[j]); // push to array
        }
        html.push('<br />');
    }
    var create = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('Build html: ' + (create-start));
    this.innerHTML = html.join(''); // use innerHTML
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('Update html: ' +(end-create));
}
```

Of course, these are just simple JavaScript optimizations (which aren't really that useful on the newer browsers). It sounds like you need to simplify your HTML and possibly your CSS so that it can be rendered faster by the HTML engine.

Comment: This is the fastest approach that keeps a steady refresh rate. Other suggestions to update only some characters would be much faster most of the time, but would cause things like clearing the display to be much slower in comparison. I'm marking this correct as a result. I'll be investigating outputting to a canvas element rather than html to see if its any faster.

Comment: @Justin808: I was going to suggest that, but I wasn't sure how big of a hassle the switch to canvas would be. If you have a breakthrough be sure to let us know :).

Comment: canvas is working out, and not a huge shift in my code. I'll update the example and the question when I have it up to par with the previous example

Answer (score 1):

To understand this kind of issues I find Dynatrace Ajax Edition to be the best tool because it can also tell how much time is spent in rendering and not only javascript execution. There might be other similar tools I find this one to be good.

I think you might want to rethink your whole approach. Writing HTML elements to create an animation will never be a good idead. This is the reason we have things like canvas, svg and flash/silverlight. It might be possible to optimize to a certain degree but please use the right tool instead. Maybe not the answer you were looking for but I think you will be much more pleased with the endresult both when it comes to performance but also maintainability if you use the canvas or svg for example.

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#text is a nice library

**UPDATE 1:**
If you really want to do it this way I would try to change the method a bit. Right now you redraw the whole "grid" each time. Looking at the animation it looks like you should be able to update only a row each time. I'm thinking that you can wrap each row in a div instead and for each frame you only rewrite the contents of the div on that row. I would store a reference to the divs in an array so you can avoid running the selector on each frame.

Comment: I would hate to use graphical tools for pure text. I'de use canvas as a very very last resort if I had to though, I dont want to use any plugins for this.

Comment: Updated with another approach that might help you

Comment: Thanks for the update. This issue would be a variable refresh rate with this approach. I'll look into outputting to a canvas and see if that speeds things up.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can get constant FPS with this approach. Unless the canvas works out I might make a demo when I get back home tonight.

Comment: canvas is working out, and not a huge shift in my code. I'll update the example and the question when I have it up to par with the previous example

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but maybe using the `join` function will speed it up, assuming `data.screen[i]` is an array of strings:

(the loop)

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.screen.length; i++) {
        html += data.screen[i].join("");
    html += '<br />';
}
```

Concat'ing a string might look like a simple addition, but a new string object is created on every use of `+=`. I suggest using something like a `StringBuffer`.

Edit:

Ok, in your example code, you are trying to replace thousands of lines of html every few milliseconds, changing only one character each time. If you only changed one character each time, you could cut down on the delay by ~99%

Comment: True, but the whole screen can scroll up, all chars would need replaced. I need a steady refresh rate, not a variable one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the issue is with actually appending the data and not rendering the data? If your markup is complex (many `span`s might be, depending on how many there are), then the rendering time for the new markup is non-negligible. What happens to the time if you change the call to `.html(html)` to `.text(html)`?

I'm not suggesting you do this as a final fix (`text` doesn't parse HTML tags), but it could help you see if the time is taken rendering or appending.

Comment: Yeah, changing this to .text makes it about 1ms as well... it seems to be render time. Problem is I need the style information for each character.